# eclipse can not open market place

Tags: eclipse

When I try to open the Market place in eclipse I always get this error message:

```
    Cannot open Eclipse Marketplace
Cannot install remote marketplace locations: Resource not found: Not Found
Cannot complete request to http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p: Resource not found: Not Found
Resource not found: Not Found
Not Found
Resource not found: Not Found
Not Found
Resource not found: Not Found
Not Found
```

I tried to delete my workspace and creat a new one to download a new version of eclipse and I change my proxy settings already to manual or direct. But I am still able to update my eclipse but as soon as I open the market place I get this error. On my computer I do not have any proxy settings.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in the current Eclipse. Which Eclipse IDE package of which version do you run with which Java?

Comment: I use "eclipse-jee-2021-09-R-macosx-cocoa-x86_64" and my java version is "17 2021-09-14 LTS".